# Add an hour to a time value on php

Tags: php, sql, strtotime

I have a form that people are filling in and adding appointment times to, im then inputting the form into a sql db. Im then making a sheet and that shows the appointment slot. All that I need to to is add 1 hour to the appointment slot time. I have a variable call $time that is the appointment time I have tried the following:

```
<?php 
$time=strtotime("+3600"); 
$final=date("H:i",$time);
echo $final;
```

but it comes back with all different times any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Ever thought of punching this into Google? "add one hour strtotime php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time=strtotime("+1 hour"); 
$time=strtotime("+60 minutes");
```

[Strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) means: String to time, very useful method when working with dates in PHP.

Or like below answer:

```
$time = time() + 3600;
```

Note that you should avoid calculation with strings, that is: A number between quotes. (string)"3600" vs (int)3600

Comment: Hi cant seem to get it to work I have just tried    <?php 
  $time=time() + '3600';
  $final=date("H:i",$time);
  echo $final; ?> I have 20:00 in the original time but it is returning 16:44 when i put it through the code

Comment: I suspect that the time on your server is wrong.
Try this:
`<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;?>`
This gives you the servertime  which should be the current time (or +x hours for other timezones). 

Depending on what type of machine you are working on, you have to update this

Comment: If this isn't the case, try google for `ntp update [Server OS]`